# Mocking local module with isolateModules

Tags: jestjs, react-easy-state

I'm using `react-easy-state` and I want to reset the store on each test. Which works fine. But when I try to mock a local module the mocked function does not get called. The mocking works fine without the use of `isolateModules`.

How do I do mocking on a module in conjunction with `isolateModules`?

This is what I'm trying to do:

```
  beforeEach(() => {
    jest.doMock('./util/getValidPosition', () => {
      return { getValidPosition: jest.fn() };
    });
    jest.isolateModules(() => {
      store = require('./store').workspace;
    });
  });

  afterEach(() => {
    jest.resetModules();
  });
```

Comment: *But when I try to mock a local module the mocked function does not get called* - the question doesn't contain the relevant code. But I'm quite sure that's because you didn't import dependent modules. The purpose of isolateModules is to import all dependencies inside.

Comment: @EstusFlask That works, thanks. You want to create an answer so I can accept it?